# jquery .find() method -- parameter composed of doms joined by comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen code like this, a`jQuery.find()` with parameters split by commas, i.e. `div, input, select`.

```
newRow.find('div, input, select').each(function() {
  ......
});
```

What does it mean? Is it something like "a select input box under div"? I couldn't find official document on this function.

Comment: Check this one: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Here is an explanation on how multiple selectors work in jQuery:  http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Just to be clear, you are only passing one parameter into `.find()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided would look in the object `newRow` for any `div`, `input` or `select` elements and it would then run the code in the `each` function for each one it finds.

Answer (score 8):

It's a CSS selector.  Known as "grouping", it means 'find all `div`, `input` and `select` elements'.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping

Comment: Thank you. So all of the elements regardless of parent-children relationship?